# Name from history meaning charismatic?

Tags: synonyms, history, names

Much like McGyver meaning "resourceful," Einstein meaning "intelligent," Savant meaning "gifted..." I remember hearing and using a name to refer to someone as a charismatic go-getter. Another word that comes to mind is "maverick."

Comment: I don't usually associate guile and cunning with charisma...but perhaps that's just me.

Comment: Well he used his charisma to charm and deceive people. It's not a necessary trait of charisma but they help each other.

Comment: I remember the name most often used for a man who is good with women. I may be remembering incorrectly.

Comment: Casanova. Haha nevermind I found it.

Comment: I was wrong about my initial description of him. Sorry.

Comment: _Savant_ isn't a personal name - it's French for 'one who knows'.

Comment: Rasputin was charismatic.

Comment: Christ-like https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/christlike

Comment: Who's the audience? For example, there might be an example who's well-known in, say, Australia, but wouldn't be well-known to an American audience, or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

There's arguably a snowclone '**He's the Napoleon of** ...'

- *The Napoleon of Crime: The Life and Times of Adam Worth, the Real Moriarty* [[Ben Macintyre {after Conan Doyle}; Waterstones](https://www.waterstones.com/book/the-napoleon-of-crime/ben-macintyre/9780006550624)]
- *The Napoleon of blackmail, Charles Augustus Magnussen** [' ... Magnussen was a powerful and wealthy businessman who ran his own media firm CAM Global. He was a known blackmailer, referred to by Sherlock Holmes as the 'Napoleon of blackmail', and had much control over the Western world due to his blackmailing.'] [[Baker Street Wiki](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+Napoleon+of+blackmail%22+-Notting&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&biw=1314&bih=755&ei=tmPGZIjdJOG0hbIPheOtuAk&ved=0ahUKEwiIkIT4wraAAxVhWkEAHYVxC5cQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=%22the+Napoleon+of+blackmail%22+-Notting&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiJCJ0aGUgTmFwb2xlb24gb2YgYmxhY2ttYWlsIiAtTm90dGluZ0joKFDmBliiJXABeACQAQCYATegAbkEqgECMTG4AQPIAQD4AQHiAwQYASBBiAYB&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)]
- *The Napoleon of Protection* ... *William McKinley* ... [[Papertrell](https://www.papertrell.com/apps/preview/The-Handy-Presidents-Answer-Book/Handy%20Answer%20book/Who-was-called-The-Napoleon-of-Protection/001137020/content/SC/52cb051982fad14abfa5c2e0_default.html#:%7E:text=William%20McKinley%20was%20called%20The,an%20extremely%20high%20tariff%20law.)]
- *The Napoleon of The Prize Ring: Jack McAuliffe* [[Nat Fleischer; Abe Books](https://www.abebooks.co.uk/first-edition/Jack-McAuliffe-Napoleon-Prize-Ring-Fleischer/31406572211/bd)]
- *"The Napoleon of the Turf"*, Col. William R. Johnson [[A L Dick; Artist: Yale University Art Gallery](https://artgallery.yale.edu/collections/objects/45923)]

and many locational examples:

- *The Napoleon of the West, Santa Ana* [[Frank C. Hanighen; Abe Books](https://www.abebooks.co.uk/signed-first-edition/Santa-Ana-Napoleon-West-Frank-Hanighen/31138519663/bd)]
- *The Napoleon of the Pacific, Kamehameha the Great* [[Francis H. Bacon; Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Napoleon-Pacific-Kamehameha-Classic-Reprint/dp/B00887CBSG)]
- *The Napoleon of India: 'Samudragupta (335-375 AD) of the Gupta dynasty is known as the "Napoleon of India".'* [[The Times of India](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/who-is-known-as-the-napoleon-of-india/articleshow/756074.cms)]

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/napoleon) acknowledges the usage:

> *Napoleon* [3]: one like Napoleon I (as in ambition)

most would add 'rapacious, brilliant, charismatic, infamous'. [Dan Snow](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/europe/france/11472205/The-French-should-end-their-love-affair-with-Napoleon-he-was-an-utterly-brutal-and-callous-dictator.html) in his 2015 article for the Telegraph certainly would.

Comment: The blackmailer in the Sherlock Holmes adventure was named Charles Augustus Milverton. According to Wiki, Doyle based him on a real man, Charles Augustus Howell.

Comment: Charles Augustus Magnussen* was played by Lars Mikkelsen in the TV adaptation 'Sherlock' ... where names are often mangled, to protect the guilty.

Answer (score 0):

[Giacomo "Casanova"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giacomo_Casanova)

A man considered romantic and gallant, especially one who gives amorous attentions to women. A promiscuous, philandering man.

Comment: As Wikipedia notes, his name is _synonymous with "libertine"_ rather than the more general "charisma".

Comment: Huh, I always thought it was a compliment. Though I suppose it still could be depending on who you ask.

Comment: I think the thing is that a *casanova* is likely to be charismatic, but is always descriptive of a libertine. However, being charismatic certainly doesn't mean a chap is a libertine. However, there may be a answer to your question (about a name synonymous with *charismatic*) which is not Casanova.

Comment: The question asks for a word for a "charismatic go-getter". I'm not sure Casanova could be described as a go-getter; for "charismatic go-getter" I'd think more of the mentioned Rasputin or more positively someone like JFK or Justin Trudeau.

Comment: I asked NGrams to [list the most common words](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*+was+a+charismatic+leader&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) before **...was a charismatic leader.** Sadly, I have to report that (ignoring pronouns), ***Hitler*** just beat ***Jesus*** to the top slot. The other proper nouns in the top 10 are ***Nasser, Garvey** (who he?), and **Gandhi***.

Answer (score 0):

If you can accept mythology, rather than history:

[Adonis](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/adonis)

- Classical Mythology. a youth slain by a wild boar but permitted by Zeus to pass four months every year in the lower world with Persephone, four with Aphrodite, and four wherever he chose.
- a very handsome young man.